# How to replace 'Shift+Return' with 'Return' in a Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with 'Shift+Return' (showed as arrow from top to down and left) instead of 'Return' (end paragraph), so, if I try to justify, I got a wrong formatting.

I've tried to replace with this:

```
WordBasic.EditReplace Find:=Chr(11), Replace:=vbCrLf, Direction:=0, MatchCase:=0, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=1
```

and this:

```
WordBasic.EditReplace Find:=Chr(11), Replace:=vbNewLine, Direction:=0, MatchCase:=0, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=1
```

but I get a "square" as first char of the new line.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, Word uses only
carriage return for "Paragraph Mark" (`vbCr` = `Chr(13)`, or `^p` special character)
and vertical tab for "Manual Line Break" (`vbVerticalTab` = `Chr(11)`, or `^l` special character)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
WordBasic.EditReplace Find:=Chr(11), Replace:="^p", Direction:=0, MatchCase:=0, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=1
```

or

```
WordBasic.EditReplace Find:="^l", Replace:="^p", Direction:=0, MatchCase:=0, WholeWord:=0, PatternMatch:=0, SoundsLike:=0, ReplaceAll:=1, Format:=0, Wrap:=1
```